# can't concatenate string with .join using python. TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, join, concatenation

I try to add some information to the db table with method 'insert_users'. The problem associated with concatenation of variable self.tests2 to INSERT query, when i try do this i have: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.  When I try to insert instead of 'self.test2' string '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s' all works. What the matter?

```
def insert_users(self, users_dict, rows_names):
        self.test1 = len(rows_names) * ["%s"]
        print self.test1
        self.test2 = "'" + "','".join(self.test1) + "'"
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        for name, val in users_tuple.items():
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users(""" + \
            ",".join(rows_names) + """) VALUES(""" + **self.test2** + """)""" %\
            (name, val, 'SomeNickname', 'password', '13-09-11', '2', '@gmail.com','1'))
        ConnectToDb.connection_cot_cle(self)

users_dict = {'FirstName':'LastName'}
rows_names = ('Fname', 'Lname', 'login', 'password','reg_date', 'role_id',\
              'email', 'is_active')
db_instans.insert_users(users_dict, rows_names)
```

Comment: either name or val isn't a string. So use ``str(val)`` and then try ``str(name)`` to see which one isnt converted to string.

Comment: val and name are dictionary

Comment: Where is `users_tuple` coming from? You don't list that definition. You have `users_dict` though. Just using the wrong variable?

Comment: i  did mistake when created this post. In program i caused user_dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use temporary variable to save your string like:

```
temp = "INSER INTO users(" + ",".join(rows_names) + ") VALUES(" + test2 + ")" 
temp = temp % (name, val, 'SomeNickname', 'password', '13-09-11', '2', '@gmail.com','1')
```

and then interpolate data into it

or add additional parentheses around

```
("INSER INTO users(" + ",".join(rows_names) + ") VALUES(" + test2 + ")")
```

it will look like

```
temp = ("INSER INTO users(" + ",".join(rows_names) + ") VALUES(" + test2 + ")") % (name, val, 'SomeNickname', 'password', '13-09-11', '2', '@gmail.com','1')
```

problem is that you didn't have complete string, and wanted to insert data into ")"